# in renderPieChart: The data must be made up of two columns, 'name' and 'value'

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am trying to filter my data set which have 19 columns and 5 rows. I just want column 12 and 16 with row no 1 and 2.  Here is my code

```
dat2<-data.frame(FundingIAS2018[c(1,2),c(12,13)])
renderPieChart(div_id = "grant2017",
           data=dat2)
```

it gives error:
"Warning: Error in renderPieChart: The data must be made up of two columns, 'name' and 'value'
  -49: stop
  -48: renderPieChart"

Comment: Extending on my answer: your test speaks of columns 12 and 16, your code uses columns 12 and 13. That actually might be the cause of your error already. If this turns out to be just a typo in here, please refer to my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ECharts2Shiny/versions/0.2.13/topics/renderPieChart), `data` is required to have a special formatting. If you input a `data.frame`, it needs to have two columns only, one of which must be named `name` and the other one `value`, the later has to be of numeric or integer type, too.

Assuming your data have the correct format, adding a line like

```
names(dat2) = c('name', 'value')
```

right before your `renderPieChart` command should resolve the error